# mysql объединение двух таблиц

Tags: mysql

есть две таблицы
`user`

```
|id|user|
1 | kolya
2 | fedya
```

и `data` в которую периодически записываются `count`

```
|user_id|data_time|count|
1 | 2019-04-26 15:41:55 | 8
2 | 2019-04-26 15:41:55 | 15
1 | 2019-04-26 15:28:55 | 25
2 | 2019-04-26 15:28:55 | 28
1 | 2019-04-25 15:20:55 | 6
2 | 2019-04-25 15:20:55 | 3
1 | 2019-04-25 15:10:55 | 23
2 | 2019-04-25 15:10:55 | 29
```

Как мне при запросе объединить эти две таблицы и сделать выборку в таком формате

```
|id|user|последний count за сегодня|последний count за вчера|
```

Comment: Вот бы в базе данные увидеть, просто пару строк для примера в 1 и во второй таблице

Comment: Вот немножко не понял про последний count за сегодня и последний за вчера. Какой ответ должен получиться на выходе? и для наглядности даты измените на сегодня и вчера пожалуйста )

Comment: Прочитайте про `JOIN`.

Comment: @new_user такой ответ должен быть: `1 | 2019-04-26 15:41:55 | 8 | 6`
вторая строка `2 | 2019-04-26 15:41:55 | 15 | 3`?

Comment: @RifmaMan Да именно он

Answer (score 0):

В моем примере, таблица `temp_user` соответствует вашей `user`, аналогично и с таблицей `count`. Данные в таблицах указаны на основании вашего примера и на выходе я имею результат который пытался добиться от вас в комментарии (как и описание задачи с явным указанием того что есть, и что должно быть на выходе).

Вкратце, берем за основу таблицу с пользователями (ведь каждый уникален) далее подгружаем таблицу с "событиями" `count` привязывая её по `user_id` фильтруем по нужной дате, сортируем, чтобы получить последний "каунт", дальше подгружаем и сортируем аналогично вторую копию таблицы `count`. Ну и в конце (к сожалению не знаю как сделать иначе) в строке `LIMIT 2` нужно указать зная заранее сколько у нас пользователей в таблице `user`

```
SELECT
    `today`.`id`,
    `today`.`user_id`,
    `today`.`count` AS `today_count`,
    `yesterday`.`count` AS `yesterday_count`
FROM
    `temp_user`
JOIN `temp_count` AS `today`
ON
    `today`.`user_id` = `temp_user`.`id`
JOIN `temp_count` AS `yesterday`
ON
    `yesterday`.`user_id` = `temp_user`.`id`
WHERE
    `today`.`data_time` > '2019-04-26 00:00:00' AND `today`.`data_time` < '2019-04-26 23:59:59' AND `yesterday`.`data_time` > '2019-04-25 00:00:00' AND `yesterday`.`data_time` < '2019-04-25 23:59:59'
ORDER BY
    `today`.`data_time` DESC,
    `yesterday`.`data_time` DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: нужно использовать  groupe by

Comment: @new_user если использовать group by, то сортировка не будет работать

Comment: сортировка мне не нужна

Answer (score 0):

если mysql 8, то можно так, например

```
select id, user , sum(last_cnt_today), sum(last_cnt_yestoday)
from (
select distinct user_id 
, date(data_time)
,case 
  when date(data_time)=CURDATE() then
  LAST_VALUE(count) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, date(data_time) order by user_id, data_time 
RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
else 0
end as last_cnt_today
,case 
  when date(data_time)=( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ) then
  LAST_VALUE(count) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, date(data_time) order by user_id, data_time 
RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
else 0
end as last_cnt_yestoday  
from data d
where data_time >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ) 
) q
, user u
where q.user_id=u.id
group by id, user;
```

а если более ранний, то можно так

```
select id, user, sum(last_count_today), sum(last_count_yestoday )
from (
select id, user
, case 
  when date(dt)=CURDATE() then
  (select count from data where data_time=max_dt.dt and user_id=u.id)
  else 0
  end as last_count_today
, case 
  when date(dt)=(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) then
  (select count from data where data_time=max_dt.dt and user_id=u.id)
  else 0
  end as last_count_yestoday  
from user u,
(select user_id, max(data_time) as dt from data
where data_time >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ) 
group by user_id, date(data_time)) max_dt
where max_dt.user_id=u.id) q
 group by id, user
```